# What does Windows do with unused serial port data

Tags: uwp, serial-port

I've got an application with a USB device (of my own making, so it can be modified to certain extents) that pumps data out nonstop, at tightly controlled intervals on the order of 12 bytes every 61 microseconds.

On the host side, which is a Windows 10 computer running one a UWP app, I only use this data on demand. Typically I'll grab one second of data at a time, split it into various arrays, then do some DSP on it to extract the info I'm after from the USB device.

My question is about the data being sent to the COM port while my UWP app isn't listening. Can I listen on demand, and just ignore an open COM port that's constantly having data thrown at it? Should I reprogram my USB device to provide data on demand?

Comment: Win10 is an OS that uses the CPU in protected mode.  Any OS in protected mode does not allow (user) programs direct access to hardware.  The program "reads" (or what you call *"listen"*) from system buffers, which can over-run when data is received faster than the program "reads" it.  Typically when the buffer is full, the OS retains the (older) existing data in the buffer, and newly received data is tossed.  At a rate of 12 bytes every 61usec, you're almost guaranteed to consistently overrun the buffer.

Comment: In that case, aren't you creating your own firmware and device drivers? It seems like a waste to occupy the bandwidth of the bus to send and receive data that you don't use. Shouldn't you add a command to the device to start/stop sending data?

Comment: @kunif yeah, that seems like the most reasonable way to do it. That's how I had previous versions of my hardware working, but I was wondering what would happen if I removed that command.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is about the data being sent to the COM port while my UWP app isn't listening. Can I listen on demand, and just ignore an open COM port that's constantly having data thrown at it?

For your requirement, [`SerialPort.Handshake`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Handshake);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)  Property suit the scenario. And `System.IO.Ports` could be used in uwp platform. And you could refer KazukiOta's [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/how-to-access-virtual-com-port-from-uwp-app/ba-p/720864) here.

> *When handshaking is used, the device connected to the SerialPort object is instructed to stop sending data when there is at least (ReadBufferSize-1024) bytes in the buffer. The device is instructed to start sending data again when there are 1024 or fewer bytes in the buffer. If the device is sending data in blocks that are larger than 1024 bytes, this may cause the buffer to overflow.*